# past participle and past simple

Tags: grammar, past-simple, past-participles

1. The paintings ***have been proven*** to be fakes
2. The paintings ***proved*** to be fakes

Questions:

1. What is the difference between using ***has been proven*** and ***proved***? I know one is a past participle and one is past simple but I don't know when to use them.
2. Can I use past participle without has or have for example The paintings proven to be fakes?

Answer (score 0):

**Tense of present perfect:** has + pp / have + pp
Present perfect
Level: beginner

The present perfect is formed from the present tense of the verb have and the past participle of a verb.

We use the present perfect:

for something that started in the past and continues in the present:

They've been married for nearly fifty years.
She has lived in Liverpool all her life.

when we are talking about our experience up to the present:
I've seen that film before.
I've played the guitar ever since I was a teenager.
He has written three books and he is working on another one.

We often use the adverb ever to talk about experience up to the present:

My last birthday was the worst day I have ever had.

and we use never for the negative form:

Have you ever met George?
Yes, but I've never met his wife.

- you should use "have or has" together with "past participle"

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-perfect

Answer (score 0):

- The paintings have been proven to be fakes

The painting have been proven [by art experts] to be fakes. This is a sentence using the present perfect in passive form.

- The paintings proved to be fakes.

proved = turned out to be, not a passive.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate issues here: tense, and choice of verb.

*Prove* is most often transitive, in the sense "To demonstrate that something is true or viable; to give proof for". But it has a less common intransitive sense  "To turn out; to manifest". (Senses 1 and 2 from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prove#Verb))

Your first sentence is passive (*BE + part participle* is either adjectival or passive), and so corresponds to the transitive sense: it means that evidence has been found which established that they are fakes.

Your second sentence is intransitive, and so *prove* has the second meaning: the paintings turned out to be fakes. It says nothing about how this was established, or how solid the conclusion was.

Separately, there's the question of tense, which BEBYGONES discussed. Either form can be used in either tense:

> The paintings have been proved/proven to be fakes. (perfect, passive).

> The paintings were proved/proven to be fakes. (simple past, passive)

> The paintings have proved/proven to be fakes. (perfect, active)

> The paintings proved to be fakes. (simple past, active)

All of these are perfectly grammatical and idiomatic: the choice depends on what you want to say.

Both *proved* and *proven* are used as past participles. Wiktionary  says:

> As the past participle of prove, proven is often discouraged,
> with proved preferred – “have proved” rather than “have proven”; the
> prescriptivism is however rarely observed in practice. They are both
> equally common in everyday use in American and Canadian English. Both
> are used and considered correct in British English, but “have proved”
> is more common.[3](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prove#Verb)[2] Note as well the somewhat comparable
> differences in conjugation with “have snuck” and “have dove” (American
> English and Canadian English) as opposed to “have sneaked” and “have
> dived” (British English), with regional exceptions.

As for your question 2, *The paintings proven to be fakes* is a perfectly good noun phrase, but it is not a sentence. *proven to be fakes* is a participial clause modifying *paintings*.